# Sorting Custom DateTime C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, listbox, datetimepicker

I need help sorting custom DateTime in listbox in descending order.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy  HH:mm";



        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker1.Value).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"));
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy  HH:mm";   
        }
    }
}
```

I add the text from textBox1 and date and time from DateTimePicker1, I would like it to sort automatically depending on the time.

Thanks !

Comment: How you change time? I think when you will run your program it will get time from your system's date time and time will never changed.

Comment: Time comes from dateTimePicker1, i want to sort these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have maintained a `List<string>` for the purpose:

try this:

```
    List<string> lst;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy  HH:mm";          
        lst = new List<string>();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        lst.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        BindList();            
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        string s = textBox1.Text + ", " + Convert.ToDateTime(this.dateTimePicker1.Value).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm");
        lst.Add(s);
        BindList();          
    }

    private void BindList()
    {  
        lst = (lst.OrderByDescending(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(" "), s.Length - s.LastIndexOf(" ")))).ToList();
        listBox1.DataSource = lst;
    }
```